# Laravel collective select placeholder not working when multiple is to true {{ Form::select() }}

Tags: laravel, select, twitter-bootstrap-3, tags, laravelcollective

I have a problem with Laravel collective select placeholder not working

```
 {{ Form::select('album',$albums,$selected, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'select album' ]) }}
```

But when i allow tags to true like this using select 2, it works fine,

```
 {{ Form::select('tags[]',$tags,$tagged, ['data-input'=>'select2-tags','multiple'=>true]) }}
```

The second one works fine, I don't want the album to have multiple input attribute, What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `select`, but you can add placeholder as the value with `0` index:

```
$albums[0] = 'select album';
```

Alternatively, you can create your own select function using [Laravel Collective Form macros](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#custom-macros).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this :

```
 {{ Form::select('album', $album , Input::old('album'), array('placeholder' => 'Please select','class'=>'form-control')) }}
```